# "Undefined reference to" error declaring an object with a double template class

Tags: c++, templates

I've got a class that uses a two-arguments template:

```
template<class T, class R>
```

When I try to declare an object in `main.cpp` it says: "undefined reference to `FileTest<int, int>::FileTest()`

Here's the code:

**FileTest.h**

```
#ifndef FILETEST_H
#define FILETEST_H
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

....

using namespace std;

template<class T, class R>
class FileTest : public FileInput , FileOutput
{

    public:
        FileTest();

        FileTest(const string nome_file):FileInput(nome_file),FileOutput(nome_file){
        };

        virtual ~FileTest();

        void setNewEntry(const T id_domanda,const R id_risposta);

        ...



    private:
        ...

};
template<class T, class R>
FileTest<T,R>::~FileTest()
{
    //dtor
}


template<class T, class R>

void FileTest<T, R>::setNewEntry(const T id_domanda,const R id_risposta){
  /*
    sets new entry in a vector
*/


}

#endif // FILETEST_H
```

**main.cpp**

```
 #include <iostream>

    #include "FileTest.h"

    using namespace std;

int main()
{

    FileTest<int, int>  object;
    return 0;
}
```

Error (in main.cpp) :

> undefined reference to `FileTest<int, int>::FileTest()`

When I try with another class which has only one template argument, everything is working! What's the cause of this error?

Comment: No its not the problem i guess.

Comment: @Niall No, it's not that problem in this case.

Comment: @Niall - Its not duplicate. If you look carefuly you will see that templates *are* implemented in header file. Problem is solved in answers section.

Answer (score 2):

You declared a zero parameter constructor for FileTest:

```
template<class T, class R>
class FileTest : public FileInput , FileOutput
{

    public:
        FileTest();
```

But I can't see an implementation for that method anywhere. As this is a constructor for a template class, its implementation should be in the header file somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem**

You have declared constructor without parameters

```
FileTest();
```

but didnt provide his definition anywhere, so linker won't find it and this will result in *"undefined reference to"* if you would attempt to call this function.

This constructor without paramters is called when constructing object in main `FileTest<int, int>  object;`)

---

**Fix**

Change constructor to

```
FileTest() {}
```

or

```
FileTest() = default;
```